# Program pauses after opening internet shortcut

Tags: batch-file

> Backstory: I was trying to create a program, in batch, that automatically opens 4 internet shortcuts. Problem: It opens the shortcut once, but then automatically runs a pause command, which if you unpause kills the program entirely

**Code**

```
cd C:\Users\matth\Desktop
bing.url
bing.url
bing.url
bing.url
```

Comment: may be you can used prefix start url;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found adding quotation marks and the prefix start with a set of quotation marks afterward works. For instance,

```
 cd C:\Users\matth\Desktop
 start "" "bing.url"
 start "" "bing.url"
 start "" "bing.url"
 start "" "bing.url"
```

Answer (score 0):

@Zieo The following will work on Windows 10. You just need to know which browser is being used.

Microsoft Edge - Below would open the 3 URLs as 3 Tabs in the one window.

```
@echo off
start microsoft-edge:https://stackoverflow.com
start microsoft-edge:https://superuser.com
start microsoft-edge:https://serverfault.com
:eof
```

Google Chrome - Below would open the 3 URLs as 3 Tabs in the one window.

```
@echo off
start chrome.exe https://stackoverflow.com
start chrome.exe https://superuser.com
start chrome.exe https://serverfault.com
:eof
```

Chrome also has the `--new-window` argument to open a URL in a new Window instead of another Tab in current Window.

For example the below would open all 3 URLs in separate Chrome Windows.

```
@echo off
start chrome.exe https://stackoverflow.com --new-window
start chrome.exe https://superuser.com --new-window
start chrome.exe https://serverfault.com --new-window
:eof
```